What's the maximum of $(\sin A-\sin B)(\sin B-\sin C)(\sin A-\sin C)$ in one triangle?
What's the maximum of $(\sin A-\sin B)(\sin B-\sin C)(\sin A-\sin C)$ in one triangle (suppose $\sin A\geq\sin B\geq\sin C$)?
The result from Mathematica is that when $A\approx1.95398,B\approx0.913057,C\approx0.274556$, $(\sin A-\sin B)(\sin B-\sin C)(\sin A-\sin C)$ reaches its maximum, which is $0.0464758$. I've made some attempts and a few things have been known.
First, according to the law of sines, we have $\displaystyle (\sin A-\sin B)(\sin B-\sin C)(\sin A-\sin C)=\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{8R^3}$. Since $a\geq b\geq c$, we have $\displaystyle (a-b)(b-c)\leq\frac{(a-b+b-c)^2}{4}=\frac{(a-c)^2}{4}$, and then $\displaystyle \frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{8R^3}\leq\frac{(a-c)^3}{32R^3}$. With $a-c<2R$, we have $\displaystyle \frac{(a-c)^3}{32R^3}\leq\frac{1}{4}$. However, this is much greater than the desired result $0.0464758$.
Second, I've tried to use the identity $\displaystyle \sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$. Then $\displaystyle (\sin A-\sin B)(\sin B-\sin C)(\sin A-\sin C)=8\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cos\frac{A+C}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{B-C}{2}\sin\frac{A-C}{2}$. The maximum of $\displaystyle \cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cos\frac{A+C}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{B-C}{2}\sin\frac{A-C}{2}$ are both known, which are $0.125$ and $0.25$ respectively.
Proof \begin{aligned}&\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cos\frac{A+C}{2}\\=&\cos\frac{\pi-C}{2}\cos\frac{\pi-A}{2}\cos\frac{\pi-B}{2}\\=&\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}\\=&e^{\ln\sin\frac{A}{2}+\ln\sin\frac{B}{2}+\ln\sin\frac{C}{2}}.\end{aligned}
Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\ln\sin\frac{x}{2}$, then $\displaystyle f(x)'=\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{x}{2}$, and then $f(x)''<0$. By Jensen's inequality, we have $$\ln\sin\frac{A}{2}+\ln\sin\frac{B}{2}+\ln\sin\frac{C}{2}\leq 3\ln\sin\frac{A+B+C}{2\times3}=-3\ln2,$$ and therefore $\displaystyle \cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cos\frac{A+C}{2}\leq e^{-3\ln2}=\frac{1}{8}$.
On the other hand, it's obvious that $\displaystyle \sin\frac{B-C}{2}\leq \sin\frac{B+\frac{C}{2}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \sin\frac{A-C}{2}\leq \sin\frac{A+\frac{C}{2}}{2}$. Then we have \begin{aligned}&\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{B-C}{2}\sin\frac{A-C}{2}\\ \leq&\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{A+\frac{C}{2}}{2}\sin\frac{B+\frac{C}{2}}{2} \\ =&\sin\frac{2A+C-\pi}{2}\sin\frac{A+\frac{C}{2}}{2}\sin\frac{\pi-(A+\frac{C}{2})}{2}\\ =&-\cos(A+\frac{C}{2})\sin\frac{A+\frac{C}{2}}{2}\cos\frac{A+\frac{C}{2}}{2}\\=&-\frac{1}{2}\cos(A+\frac{C}{2})\sin(A+\frac{C}{2})\\=&-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2A+C)=-\frac{1}{4}\sin(\pi+A-B)\\=&\frac{1}{4}\sin(A-B)\leq\frac{1}{4}.\end{aligned}
Then $\displaystyle 8\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{B+C}{2}\cos\frac{A+C}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}\sin\frac{B-C}{2}\sin\frac{A-C}{2}\leq 8\times\frac{1}{8}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$, which is the same result we've obtained before.
By the way, if the result from Mathematica is right, I observed that $A-B$ is very close to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{3}$ when it reaches maximum. However, I cannot go any further. Any help will be appreciated. The code for Mathematica is as follows.
expr = (Sin[A] - Sin[B]) (Sin[A] - Sin[C]) (Sin[B] - Sin[C]);
result = NMaximize[{expr, 0 < A < Pi, 0 < B < Pi, 0 < C < Pi, A + B + C == Pi, Sin[A] > Sin[B], Sin[B] > Sin[C]}, {A, B, C}]


The answer is $3\sqrt{15}/250$.
First I substituted $C = \pi - A - B$ in your expression (call it $F$),
and set to $0$ the partial derivatives with respect to $A$ and $B$ to get two equations in terms (when expanded) of  $\sin(A)$, $\cos(A)$, $\sin(B)$, $\cos(B)$.  Substitute $\sin(A) = a$, $\cos(A) = c$, $\sin(B) = b$, $\cos(B)=d$;
now we have two polynomial equations in $a,b,c,d$ plus $a^2+c^2 - 1 = 0$ and
$b^2 + d^2 - 1 = 0$.  One more polynomial equation: $F - r = 0$ with $F$ expressed in terms of $a,b,c,d$. Then use a Groebner basis of these $5$ polynomials to get a polynomial in $r$ alone, which turns out to be
$$12500 r^5 - 50027 r^3 + 108 r = r (12500 r^2 - 27) (r - 2) (r + 2)$$
The value $2$ turns out not to correspond to a real solution, so the correct
maximum is the positive root of $12500 r^2 - 27$, which is $3 \sqrt{15}/250$.
[EDIT] Here is my Maple code.
F:= (sin(A)-sin(B))*(sin(B)-sin(C))*(sin(A)-sin(C));
   F:= eval(F,{C=Pi-A-B});
   dFdA:= diff(F,A); dFdB:= diff(F,B);
   eqs:= subs(sin(A)=a,cos(A)=c,sin(B)=b,cos(B)=d,
expand({dFdA,dFdB,F-r,a^2+c^2-1,b^2+d^2-1}));
   G:= Groebner:-Basis(eqs,plex(a,b,c,d,r));
   factor(G[1]);

$$ r (12500 r^2 - 27)(r-2)(r+2) $$

can you tell us when is it obtained?

Yes, I obtained the same result by using resultant.

Some thoughts.
Here we only give the maximum and one of the maximizers.
Assume that $A, B \in (0, \pi/2)$.
The maximum is $\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{250}$ when e.g.
$$\cos A = \frac45 \cos \left(\frac13 \arccos\left(-\frac{23}{32}\right)  - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + \frac25,$$
$$\cos B = \frac45 \cos \left(\frac13 \arccos\left(-\frac{23}{32}\right)\right) + \frac25.$$
(Note: $\cos A < \cos B$ are the real roots of
$50x^3 - 60x^2 + 11 = 0$.)

Good to see the trigonometric solution of the cubic !

@ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. I just found the form can be simpler. I will update it.
